# How modify an angular element, as a ng-repeat element, by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, domready

I think the problem is that angular creates these elements with javascript, so after the jQuery domready. So jQuery doesn't see those elements into the DOM. 
What can i do?

HTML

```
<li ng-prepeat="el in els">{{el.attr}}</li>
```

JS

```
$("li").click(function(){ do something });
```

Comment: try `$("li").on('click',function(){ do something });`?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, cause the event wasn't inside the domready scope.

Comment: Why the heck are you doing that anyway? Use ng-click. JQuery is for angular noobs.

Comment: James has already answered how to do this the Angular way (using `ng-click`). Most stuff you want to do can be done in Angular JS without the need for jQuery. If you find yourself in a situation where you need to use jQuery, you're most likely doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-click` to achieve the clicking of li

```
<li ng-repeat="el in els" ng-click="doSomething()">{{el.attr}}</li>
```

Comment: Can I use jQuery inside the ng-click event?

Comment: u CAN use jQuery, but you should not require it as AngularJS allows you to do the stuff you need